# Windows 10 does not connect to Sony WH-1000XM3 microphone

Tags: windows-10, microphone

I have a pair of Sony WH-1000XM3 that I am trying to use a headset and microphone simultaneously. The 3.5mm jack on the headphone is 3 pin so I bought a splitter so I could plug both splitter connections into the mic and audio jacks on my computer and plug in the headphones to the splitter. the headphones audio still work but the microphone does not. Windows 10 has access to my microphone and so do the apps I have tested this with but I have gotten no results. Bluetooth is not an option as the connection is very weak whenever I try that with my PC.

Answer (score 1):

According to the WH-1000xm3 documentation, the 3.5mm jack of the headphone is input only: the 3 pins would be the left ear, right ear, and signal ground. To include a microphone, a 4th pin would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Firmware update to version 4.2.2  Release Date: 10/30/2019 
[wh-1000xm3](https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/wireless-headphones-bluetooth-headphones/wh-1000xm3/articles/00014085)


The range of the Bluetooth connection is approximately 30 feet (10 meters). However, maximum communication range will vary depending on obstacles (person, metal, wall, etc.) or electromagnetic environment.